# Downloaded Drupal 8 with composer, now what?

Tags: installation

I'm a complete Drupal newbie trying to install Drupal 8 for the first time on a new server.  I downloaded the software following the instructions in section 3.5 of the User Guide, but there doesn't seem to be a next step.  Section 3.6 seems to be an alternate method of downloading, and nothing in 3.7 seems to be a continuation of 3.5.  How do I get back on track?

Further information:  In 3.7, it says to go to the URL I set up for the site.  When I do this, I get an index of the directory with these files and directories in it:

```
LICENSE
README.md
composer.json
composer.lock
[DIR] drush/
load.environment.php
[DIR]   logs/
phpunit.xml.dist
[DIR]   scripts/
[DIR]   vendor/
[DIR]   web/
```

I'm installing on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache 2.4, MariaDB 10.1 and php 7.2.

Comment: This means that the Apache web server is not configured to serve PHP files. Unfortunately this is kind of an odd topic for the user guide or documentation because it's hard to write documentation for other software (Apache). 3.1 doesn't go into detail about setting up Apache to serve PHP ,but that is the missing step there. However I do encourage you to share your experience on the [User Guide Project Issues page](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/user_guide?categories=All), and I think that new experiences following the guide are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Composer installs all dependencies for you

Next steps

- setup a database with user and pass
- setup so that your apache/nginx see /web as the webroot (revisit/fix this step so you can get on next step)
- visiting the URL should bring up the installation procedure which should ask for DB/user/pass, follow the instructions to complete the installation